# How to inject SavedStateHandle to ViewModel in dynamic feature module?

Tags: android, android-savedstate, dagger-hilt, dynamic-feature-module, viewmodel-savedstate

Using `@Assisted` annotation with savedStateHandle and `by viewModels()` it's possible to inject SavedStateHandle object to ViewModel in modules that are not dynamic feature modules with dagger hilt as

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}

class MainActivityViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @Assisted savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    val stringData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("hello_world")
}
```

but it's not possible for dynamic feature modules to do like this. How is it done with dynamic feature module ViewModels?

Comment: It's not possible by dagger to send dynamic parameters , you must use trick to inject.

Comment: @SaeedLotfi, i figured it out. I can post the answer when i'm available.

Comment: @Thracian mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @mtrewartha, i posted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My ViewModel is

```
class DashboardViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val dashboardStatsUseCase: GetDashboardStatsUseCase,
    private val setPropertyStatsUseCase: SetPropertyStatsUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

}
```

Creating generic `FragmentFactory` for SavedStateHandle with

```
interface ViewModelFactory<out V : ViewModel> {
    fun create(handle: SavedStateHandle): V
}

class GenericSavedStateViewModelFactory<out V : ViewModel>(
    private val viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory<V>,
    owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    defaultArgs: Bundle? = null
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
        key: String,
        modelClass: Class<T>,
        handle: SavedStateHandle
    ): T {
        return viewModelFactory.create(handle) as T
    }
}

/**
 * Convenience function to use with `by viewModels` that creates an instance of
 * [AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory] that enables us to pass [SavedStateHandle]
 * to the [ViewModel]'s constructor.
 *
 * @param factory instance of [ViewModelFactory] that will be used to construct the [ViewModel]
 * @param owner instance of Fragment or Activity that owns the [ViewModel]
 * @param defaultArgs Bundle with default values to populate the [SavedStateHandle]
 *
 * @see ViewModelFactory
 */
@MainThread
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> SavedStateRegistryOwner.withFactory(
    factory: ViewModelFactory<VM>,
    defaultArgs: Bundle? = null
) = GenericSavedStateViewModelFactory(factory, this, defaultArgs)
```

ViewModel factory for ViewModel

```
class DashboardViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val dashboardStatsUseCase: GetDashboardStatsUseCase,
    private val setPropertyStatsUseCase: SetPropertyStatsUseCase
) : ViewModelFactory<DashboardViewModel> {

    override fun create(handle: SavedStateHandle): DashboardViewModel {
        return DashboardViewModel(
            handle,
            coroutineScope,
            dashboardStatsUseCase,
            setPropertyStatsUseCase
        )
    }
}
```

And creating ViewModel using the DashBoardViewModelFactory in Fragment as

```
@Inject
lateinit var dashboardViewModelFactory: DashboardViewModelFactory

private val viewModel: DashboardViewModel
by viewModels { withFactory(dashboardViewModelFactory) }
```

[Here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/PropertyFindAR/tree/develop/features/dashboard/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/dashboard) you can see the full implementation in action. I wasn't able to find the source i used to implement this solution, if you can comment the link, i would like to give credit to author.

Comment: What about the new version of Dagger Hilt `2.32-alpha` and the new annotation `@HiltViewModel`?

Comment: @IbrahimDisouki It is related to the Hilt DI. More details here - https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html

Answer (score 0):

Dagger2
[Assisted documentation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection)

```
class MyViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    val data: Int = savedStateHandle["key"]!!
}
```

```
@AssistedFactory
interface ViewModelAssistedFactory {
    fun create(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): MyViewModel
}
```

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val viewModelAssistedFactory: ViewModelAssistedFactory
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory() {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
        key: String,
        modelClass: Class<T>,
        handle: SavedStateHandle
    ): T = viewModelAssistedFactory.create(handle) as T
}
```

Fragment

```
init {
    arguments = bundleOf("key" to 1)
}

@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory

private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory }
```

[Hilt documentation](https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html) he knows how to deliver  `SavedStateHandle`

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel()
```